# Mac OSX - Xcode Installation Directory

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

After Xcode has finished building is there a way to make it copy the executable to specific directory

> ~/Sites/cgi-bin/

I have the target `Installation Directory` set to the correct folder, with `skip installation` **unchecked**, but no luck.

Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the "Deployment Postprocessing" build setting in your target's Release configuration. Installation is normally done only with a command-line xcodebuild install, but setting Deployment Postprocessing makes it install on every build.

Ensure your user account has write privileges in the directory you want to install in, because the IDE normally doesn't run with root privileges.

Comment: I need to build a static lib for ios in xcode 4.3, i did what you suggested: set Deployment Postprocessing ON, set Install Directory to my folder's path, but it does not work. What did i miss here?

Answer (score 2):

In **build phases** down right corner Add Build Phase run script,  add such as
mv -f ${SYMROOT}/debug/projectname ~/Library/projectname

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier approach is to add a "Copy Files" build phase. Set the Destination to "Absolute Path" and the Subpath to where you want it copied on disk. Both tilde expansion and $HOME can be used in the Subpath.

Answer (score 1):

I made installation work with every build after following build settings setup:

- Set `Skip Install` to `NO`
- Set `Deployment Location` to `YES`
- Set `Installation Build Products Location` to `/`
- Set `Installation Directory` to `~/Sites/cgi-bin/`

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting the "Installation Directory", make sure you also set DSTROOT (Installation Build Productions Location) in the settings to "/".