# Xcode 4 Command Line Tool Installation Directory /usr/local/bin

Tags: macos, xcode4

I am building a Command Line Tool on Xcode 4.5.2

This has a setting:-

```
Installation Directory /usr/local/bin
```

All the build options put the output under:-

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

How do I get Xcode to use the Installation Directory?

Comment: See the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636810/mac-osx-xcode-installation-directory